# how to get a Windows CE handheld fully in sync with a desktop application

Tags: c#, sql, windows

I have an application which allows the user to do certain things (add, edit, delete records) to a database.
I have a handheld device which works in batch mode, so it is not live. When docked, it syncs its data with the database.

Until now, the tasks that the handheld has been doing were very small (only creating new records). So the way I have been doing it is to use CSV files and bounce them back and forth.

Problem is, now the handheld app is going to be significantly larger so using CSV files (chopping and changing) will become VERY messy.

I am trying to figure the best way of going about re-designing this. I could have database on the handheld which is kept in sync with the main database but I have a feeling that with the size of the DB, the handheld wouldn't be able to handle it (plus there is no need for this).

What is the neatest way of doing what I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the CSV files you could use SQL Server Compact Edition, you easily sync your data by passing the sdf file to your desktop app.

Comment: Once I have that SDF file, how do I sync individual tables and individual records. These two databases will not be identical. I will want my handheld to have some fields on it which, while ON the handheld, can be changed, then synced with the database on the desktop app.

Comment: You could use replication http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171850%28SQL.90%29.aspx